# How to code Bootstrap Simple Text Wrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im a newbie in both css, bootstrap and html5 so I'm really having a hard time coding... i hope you guys will have patience in answering some of my questions...

Anyway, this is a bootstrap 3 panel, and now I have a Tile on the panel "feature1" and an image... then a test text... I wanted to put the "test" text beside the image... making it wrap around...

I'm not really sure how to do it. but these are my codes:

```
        <div class = "row">

            <div class = "col-lg-4">

                <div class = "panel_max">

                    <div class = "panel_inside_max">

                    <h4>Feature 1</h4>

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" height="50px" width="50px">
                    <p> Test </p>

                    </div>

                </div>  

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel_max {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.panel_inside_max{
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use pull-left class for text and image to make "Test" text beside image.

Or use `float:left` property

I hope this will help you!

Comment: +1 You should also throw in a `.clearfix` in the container so it wraps the content nicely and doesn't break because of the floating. I had [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/9xkqB/) ready but you beat me to the answer.

Comment: Its not a competition. your answer is also valuable.

Comment: dont mis use stack over flow

Answer (score 1):

OK. 
Are you trying to do something like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6q33/)

If yes then you can use these `attributes`. i know could be this an older idea but it works for me.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" height="100" width="100" align="left"  vspace="10" hspace="10" style="margin-top:-5px;">
```

You can give `vertical and horizontal space` by using `vspace="10" hspace="10"`. and also margin on image to align properly.
So it will be:

```
<div class = "row">

      <div class = "col-lg-4">

           <div class = "panel_max">

                 <div class = "panel_inside_max">

                    <h4>Feature 1</h4>

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" height="50" width="50" align="left"  vspace="10" hspace="10" style="margin-top:-5px;">
                    <p> Test </p>
                    <p> Test </p>
                 </div>

            </div>  

       </div>
```